# Category of categories and anafunctors.

Tags: category-theory

1)Category of sets is a (1,0)-category, isn't it?

2)Anafunctors are the factorization of class of functors by equivalence 
relation(isomorphism) on its values, aren't they?

3)Which kind of category small categories and anafunctors forms? ((2,1)-category?) Let it be $Cat_{ana}$.

4)May I say that $Set$ is "anaisomorphic" to $Set^{op}$ (in $Cat_{ana})$? ( I can not, because of different truthness of proposition "all morphisms to the initial object are isomorphisms". Anafunctors are not related to this statement.)

Is this theory well-developed? What is worth to read about it?

Comment: To see 'all possible values' of a functor $\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ (such as a limit functor) at once, we can also use its induced **profunctor** $\mathcal A^{op}\times\mathcal B\to\mathcal{Set}$ with its cograph category which disjointly contain $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ and '*heteromorphisms*' between their objects. Then, the original assignment is given by *reflection* to $\mathcal B$, so that all target objects are equally presented this way.

Comment: @Berci, I am trying to understand what you want to say and which  question you answer. Limit functor sends functors of type A->B, where A,B-categories to objects of B, am I right? It sends natural transformations to morphisms between limits in B, am I right? (I didn't understand the rest. I also edited my post by adding answer to 4th question, is it ok?)

Comment: Every functor induces two profunctors. (Which are "cocontrabifunctor" and "contracobifunctor" :-) )

Comment: I didn't aim to answer your question, only wanted to reason about why - if not - the theory of anafunctors is not very well developed. Actually, you can choose either profunctor of any given functor. What I meant by cograph is written here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor#in_terms_of_twosided_codiscrete_cofibrations. In the cograph category,  the image of an object appears as a [co-]reflection of the object, and if we take all [co-]reflection arrows, we get sth very similar to a *saturated anafunctor*.

Comment: A $(1,0)$-category is just a groupoid, isn't it? (Which sets aren't).

Answer (score 1):

1. As stated in the comments, $Set$ is not a groupoid (which is what we mean by (1,0)-category) unless we ask it to be.
2. I'm not sure what this means, but anafunctors are certain *spans* of functors, $C\xleftarrow{J} C' \xrightarrow{F} D$, and every functor $G$ gives rise to a canonical functor $C\xleftarrow{id} C \xrightarrow{G} D$. The functor $J$ is surjective on objects and fully faithful, and the set of objects $c'$ of $C'$ in the preimage of a given object $x$ of $C$ give rise to a set of objects $F(c')$ in $D$, all of which are isomorphic, and which Makkai calls the possible values of $F$ at $c$ (think of the limit of a diagram for instance: it is not unique, but all such limits are isomorphic, and any of them will do).
3. Small categories, anafunctors and transformations form a bicategory (not strict!), which is not a (2,1)-category, unless we throw away all the non-invertible 2-arrows. If you take small *groupoids*, anafunctors and transformations, then it *is* a (non-strict) (2,1)-category, purely because all natural transformations involving groupoids are invertible.
4. Even ignoring the size distinctions (which are not important, but you have been specifying *small* categories until now), $Set$ is not equivalent to $Set^{op}$ in the bicategory of categories, anafunctors and transformations, as (for instance) $Set$ is a(n elementary) topos and $Set^{op}$ is not, and the property of being a topos is invariant under equivalence (even in the anafunctor setting).

One place to read about anafunctors in a slightly more general setting is in my paper *[Internal categories, anafunctors and localisations](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/29/26-29abs.html)*, but the construction goes back to Makkai's paper *Avoiding the axiom of choice in general category theory*, Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra **108** issue 2 (1996) pp 109-173, https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(95)00029-1, in the case of ordinary categories and to Toby Bartel's thesis *Higher Gauge Theory I: 2-Bundles* https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410328, for internal categories. There are more references at the [nLab page on anafunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor).